# fastlane gym can you skip archive and export step

Tags: ios, fastlane

Is it possible to have the fastlane gym action skip archiving and exporting to an IPA? For example, if you just have a validation build on a CI server and you don't need the output but just want to verify the compile and test steps.

Comment: did you ever find a suitable answer for this? i'm trying to accomplish the same thing

Comment: Maybe `skip_archive: true` option is what you want.

- After building, don't archive, effectively not including -archivePath param

https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/gym/#parameters

Answer (score -1):

You should check [scan](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/scan):

> `scan` makes it easy to run tests of your iOS and Mac app on a simulator or connected device

Comment: Yes I use scan for running tests, and yes it also needs to build the app for testing but the build configuration is quite different for an iOS test build vs a potential release build. So if I'm validating the integrity of the release build not sure how scan helps me